# Change Gesture Recogniser Position?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, orientation, uigesturerecognizer

I have a gesture recogniser to detect a tap on a UIImageView, however I force a position change of the image when the orientation of the iPad changes but this causes the gesture recogniser to repositioned incorrectly. How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

```
strapTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(strapTap:)];
[(UITapGestureRecognizer *)strapTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
strapTap.delegate = self;
[leatherButtonedStrap addGestureRecognizer:strapTap];
```

This above is how I setup the gesture, adding it to my UIImageView. However, something which might cause a stir is that I add the this view to my main view, remove it and then re-add it when the user presses a certain button. Hard for you to understand whats happening unless you saw the entire class, but let me know if this is enough to go on or not.

Comment: Show how you have connected your gesture recognizer to the image view. Once a gesture recognizer is added to a view, it shouldn't matter if the frame changes, the view and gesture recognizer are bound.

Comment: Edited OP. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Is the image view a property of the class? When it's removed from the view hierarchy, are you also releasing it? Is `gestureRecognizer` nil when it is re-added? Where is the gesture recognizer being added to the image view?

Comment: I'll take a look, but in the new version of Xcode release is deprecated due to ARC (automatic reference counting).

Comment: Without seeing more code we can't be sure that the image view isn't being released out from under you after it's removed from the view hierarchy. Set a breakpoint where you add the image view to the view hierarchy and check to see if the image view's `gestureRecognizer` property is nil.

Comment: What do you mean by "... gesture recogniser to repositioned ..."? Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Are you using [strapTap locationInView:leatherButtonedStrap] to get the location of the tap? This will give you the location of the tap in the coordinate system of the leatherButtonedStrap view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you're calling locationInView: in strapTap: to send the leatherButtonedStrap as the parater:

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:leatherButtonedStrap];
```

So that the location is relative to leatherButtonedStrap's coordinate system an not it's superview's.